# Is this possible to run node js file from powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I searched a lot but till now could not find anything.
I have one ps1 file and from there i want to run node js file.Is this possible 
    ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Possible. Put the below code in `.ps1` file:

```
node /path/to/file.js

or

node /path/to/file.js &        # for daemon
```

Comment: Additionally, one can add arguments as follows `node /path/to/file.js -f "C:/path/to/file.txt -c` in case the `.js` script accepts arguments like a [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) script.

Comment: how to stop existing powershell running script ?

Comment: by finding process ID and stop it. `Stop-process -Id processId`